# Header exclusion?

Tags: c++, c, header-files, lint

**Short description:**

`Header.h` has `#include <stdbool.h>` which has a Macro for _Bool in c.

`file.cpp` includes `Header.h`, but since `file.cpp` is C++ - it has bool as a native type. Now lint complains about a set of things due this (redeclaration, non-existing methods etc.). Is there a way to prevent inclusion of `<stdbool.h>` in `file.cpp` without touching `Header.h`?

If my description of a problem looks ridiculous - please throw tomatoes at me :) Otherwise, thanks for help.

**Edit:** Now thinking of this again: knowing the basic concepts of compilation and linking I should have realized that 'excluding' some header in downstream file/header sounds funny and should not be possible without cludges. But still, thanks for help. Another small brick to my understanding of this.

Comment: Complain to your library vendor. `stdbool.h` should not define `bool` and friends as macros in C++. In the mean time, `#undef`.

Comment: Can you modify `header.h`? Then just add conditional preprocessor checks for `__cplusplus` before including `<stdbool.h>`. And you might want to take a look at that linter of yours, it doesn't seem to be handling C++ very well, or it doesn't do preprocessing very well.

Comment: @T.C. it's not that simple, C++98 says nothing about `<stdbool.h>` so its effects in C++98 are unspecified. GCC's `<stdbool.h>` defines the macros for C++98, because reasons. Crappy reasons. It at least does `#define bool    bool` in C++ though, not `#define bool    _Bool` which is actively harmful.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Compatibility with code doing `#ifdef bool`, I guess?

Comment: @T.C. exactly, although I'm unconvinced such code is common enough to pander to. See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-10/msg02594.html for some history. As far as I know there was no fallout, maybe I should revisit it and try to undefine them for C++98 now as well :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create your own `stdbool.h` and put it earlier in the include path so it is found before the system one. That's technically undefined behaviour, but you have a broken `<stdbool.h>` so it's one way to work around that. Your own version could either be empty (if it will only be included by C++ files) or if you can't prevent it also being used by C files then you could do:

```
#if __cplusplus
# define __bool_true_false_are_defined   1
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
// include the real stdbool.h using the GNU #include_next extension
# include_next <stdbool.h>
#else
// define the C macros ourselves
# define __bool_true_false_are_defined   1
# define bool _Bool
# define true 1
# define false 0
#endif
```

A cleaner solution would be to do this in `file.cpp` *before* including `Header.h`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
// Undo the effects of the broken <stdbool.h> that is not C++ compatible
#undef true
#undef false
#undef bool
#include "Header.h"
```

Now when `Header.h` includes `<stdbool.h>` it will have no effect because it's already been included. This way is technically invalid (see comment below), but in practice will almost certainly work portably.

It needs to be done in every file that includes `Header.h`, so you could wrap it up in a new header and use that instead of `Header.h` e.g. `CleanHeader.h` that contains:

```
#ifndef CLEAN_HEADER_H
#define CLEAN_HEADER_H
// use this instead of Header.h to work around a broken <stdbool.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# ifdef __cplusplus
// Undo the effects of the broken <stdbool.h> that is not C++ compatible
#  undef true
#  undef false
#  undef bool
#e ndif
# include "Header.h"
#endif
```

Comment: The second approach technically violates [macro.names]/p2 :)

Comment: @T.C. doh! You're quite right, I'll correct my claim it's valid. I think it's the best solution though, since trying to write valid C++ with a non-conforming std::lib is difficult!